# Regex email special character validation

Tags: php, regex, validation

I need a regex email validation with special characters.

**Rules:**

- local part may 2 or more characters length
- local part contain special character & might not start & end with special character.
- Allow only a-z-A-Z0-9 after @

**Current Regex:**

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([\w\.\'\!\#\$\%\&\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}\~])+([a-zA-Z0-9])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,8})+$
```

**Test patterns:**

```
eee123@eee.eee > TRUE
e#e@eee.eee > TRUE
e#2@eee.eee > TRUE
ee@eee.eee > FALSE
e2@eee.eee > FALSE
#e@eee.eee > FALSE
e#@eee.eee > FALSE
```

**I need a Regex that will validate as:**

```
eee123@eee.eee > TRUE
e#e@eee.eee > TRUE
e#2@eee.eee > TRUE
ee@eee.eee > TRUE
e2@eee.eee > TRUE
#e@eee.eee > FALSE
e#@eee.eee > FALSE
```

Comment: `local part contain special character & might not start & end with special character.`

this rule contradicts your examples:
`ee@eee.eee > TRUE
e2@eee.eee > TRUE`

if there should be a special char, those should be false

Comment: Yes as you said, `ee@eee.eee > TRUE, e2@eee.eee > TRUE` & for `e#@eee.eee > FALSE, #e@eee.eee > FALSE`. Can it be possible

Comment: You should probably validate the e-mail address first using `filter_var()` and then use a regex to check only the part before the `@` for your extra special conditions...

Comment: That's a nice trick. But can it be possible just with regex. it could be better.

Comment: Can you able to avoid special characters from appearing after `@`. 
Allow only `a-z-A-Z0-9` after `@`. Can be possible to modify

Comment: Try this https://regex101.com/r/bdbz0J/2

Comment: @S.Kablar, Thanks for that. But i need more special characters. I got the answer.

Comment: Regex is evil, dont't ever use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([\w\.\'\!\#\$\%\&\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}\~])*([a-zA-Z0-9])+@([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,8}$
```

just replace + with * or ? after `([\w\.\'\!\#\$\%\&\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|}\~])`, it will match you expect.
update as you need.

Comment: Thats a nice one. Can you able to avoid special characters from appearing after `@`. Allow only `a-z-A-Z0-9` after `@`. Can be possible to modify

Comment: @Sinto, update, is that ok? just update from yours :)

Comment: Regex is evil, dont't ever use it

Answer (score 1):

While you have your answer, please note that you don't have to escape everything in square brackets, meaning:

```
^
[a-zA-Z0-9]+
([-.'!#$%&*+-\/=?^`{|}~]*)
([a-zA-Z0-9])+
@
([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+
[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,8}
$
```

does the same and is **by far** more readable. Additionally, the `*` is supposed to be **in** the parentheses.

---

As a side note, I'd rather use a simpler expression like `\S+@\S+` and actually try to send an email to that address - email addresses tend to be more complicated than previously thought.